# SATA-Device not listed in BIOS after chkdsk

Tags: ssd, bios, mount

my SSD is not listed in the BIOS - but i shall start from the beginning...

I must have improperly shut down my Windows10 as on the next boot the system would not boot up. The Windows partition was obviously identified correctly as i first got the load screen with the blue windows logo. Though afterwards the screen went black and only the circle load thing showed up... yet the system never went up - even after hours of wainting.

So i booted up with `F8` to call up the windows repair options and tried to repair the system - nothing of em worked (and i tried em all about at least twice). Also the system would not even boot up in safe mode.

Next thing - i created a linux-usb-live-device. `lsblk` showed the device `sdb` with all five partitions where `sdb2` was my c-drive and `sdb5` a data drive. I was able to `mount /dev/sdb2 /mnt/folder` and to access the data. Yet, whenever i did `mount /dev/sdb5 /mnt/foldertwo` the device just disappeared. It would not show up `lsblk` anymore. Though rebooting would bring the device back, the device would still disappear when trying to mount `sdb5` again.

So i followed a hint i found which said something like *If your ntfs partition is broken, there is no better tool to repair than `chkdsk`*. So i ran up my windows-live-usb 
and used the repair options to call up a cmd-prompt. There i ran `chkdsk c: /f` and `chkdsk d: /f`. Everything *seemed* to be fine...

I rebooted the computer and from that point my SSD does not show up anymore within the BIOS. It is therefore obviously not possible to mount or format it in any kind of way.

Is the device completely broken? Any chance to reset its boot sectors?

---

Device: Samsung Evo 250 ~5 years old

Comment: I would try removing and reinsert it again as a last resort. It's very likely the SSD is now dead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually accomplished to get it back to life! What i did:

1) Following a hint from the internet, i disconnected *only* the SATA-cable and booted up the system. It was called "powerboot". Though i did not really test the result as i directly proceeded to step 2.

2) I disconnected the power cable and removed the battery of the motherboard and waited for 30 sec.

After reconnecting everything, the SSD showed up again in the BIOS! Although, it wouldn't boot Windows10 itself, i was now able to mount the partitions using the linux-live-usb and to finally access both partitions (former c: and d:) and copy my data.